# How to get a file reference object without <input type="file"> element

Tags: javascript, chromium-embedded

Say our path is "/Users/me/cat.jpg"

How can we construct a file object in javascript referencing the file knowing the full path to the resource?

----EDIT
Security is not an issue as user has voluntarily downloaded and installed our app which runs an embedded browser.

We need a file reference that can be later used as a file object for any javascript uploader.

Comment: If you're talking browser JavaScript, that would be a bit of a security flaw, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm talking CEF, Desktop

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea — you should edit your question to reflect that, because the solution is probably special to CEF

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Input Constructed Entirely in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751482/html5-input-constructed-entirely-in-javascript)

Comment: I think if I wasn't really clear, there's no way to do this natively in JS, which is why node.js has its own API, as @MadhavanKumar mentioned. There are probably hooks to native APIs that you could use in CEF, but I don't know how that works.

Comment: Relevant? http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=10892

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodejs fs module...

```
fs.read("/path/to/file", callbackfn)
```

Comment: Will this return a file object? We need a file object to be later used in an upload operation.

Comment: there  is no such thing as File object in nodejs... however, with file path in place, nodejs supports all operations through its api. see this,  http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_statsync_path

Comment: OP says they are using Chromium Embedded Framework, which was not clearly mentioned; I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751482/html5-input-constructed-entirely-in-javascript